# Capybara + remote form request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that I'm testing using Capybara. This form's URL goes to my Braintree sandbox, although I suspect the problem would happen for any remote URL. When Capybara clicks the submit button for the form, the request is routed to the dummy application rather than the remote service.

Here's an example app that reproduces this issue: https://github.com/radar/capybara_remote. Run bundle exec ruby test/form_test.rb and the test will pass, which is not what I'd typically expect.

Why does this happen and is this behaviour that I can rely on always happening?

Comment: just tried with rspec capybara and a dummy form (routing to google) and it works as expected (post request)

Comment: @apneadiving I created this example app which reproduces the issue I'm seeing: http://github.com/radar/capybara_remote. Run `bundle exec ruby test/form_test.rb` and it'll pass.

Comment: ok, you were using Racktest: I tried with selenium. Thanks for feedback, +1

Answer (score 12):

Mario Visic points out this description in the Capybara documentation:

> Furthermore, you cannot use the RackTest driver to test a remote application, or to access remote URLs (e.g., redirects to external sites, external APIs, or OAuth services) that your application might interact with.

But I wanted to know why, so I source dived. Here's my findings:

**lib/capybara/node/actions.rb**

```
def click_button(locator)
  find(:button, locator).click
end
```

I don't care about the `find` here because that's working. It's the `click` that's more interesting. That method is defined like this:

**lib/capybara/node/element.rb**

```
def click
  wait_until { base.click }
end
```

I don't know what `base` is, but I see the method is defined twice more in `lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb` and `lib/capybara/selenium/node.rb`. The tests are using `Rack::Test` and not Selenium, so it's probably the former:

**lib/capybara/rack_test/node.rb**

```
def click
  if tag_name == 'a'
    method = self["data-method"] if driver.options[:respect_data_method]
    method ||= :get
    driver.follow(method, self[:href].to_s)
  elsif (tag_name == 'input' and %w(submit image).include?(type)) or
    ((tag_name == 'button') and type.nil? or type == "submit")
    Capybara::RackTest::Form.new(driver, form).submit(self)
  end
end
```

The `tag_name` is probably not a link -- because it's a button we're clicking -- so it falls to the `elsif`. It's definitely an `input` tag with `type == "submit"`, so then let's see what `Capybara::RackTest::Form` does:

**lib/capybara/rack_test/form.rb**

```
def submit(button)
  driver.submit(method, native['action'].to_s, params(button))
end
```

Ok then. `driver` is probably the `Rack::Test` driver for Capybara. What's that doing?

**lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb**

```
def submit(method, path, attributes)
  browser.submit(method, path, attributes)
end
```

What is this mysterious browser? It's defined in the same file thankfully:

```
def browser
  @browser ||= Capybara::RackTest::Browser.new(self)
end
```

Let's look at what this class's `submit` method does.

**lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb**

```
def submit(method, path, attributes)
  path = request_path if not path or path.empty?
  process_and_follow_redirects(method, path, attributes, {'HTTP_REFERER' => current_url})
end
```

`process_and_follow_redirects` does what it says on the box:

```
def process_and_follow_redirects(method, path, attributes = {}, env = {})
  process(method, path, attributes, env)
  5.times do
    process(:get, last_response["Location"], {}, env) if last_response.redirect?
  end
  raise Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError, "redirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects." if last_response.redirect?
end
```

So does `process`:

```
def process(method, path, attributes = {}, env = {})
  new_uri = URI.parse(path)
  method.downcase! unless method.is_a? Symbol

  if new_uri.host
    @current_host = "#{new_uri.scheme}://#{new_uri.host}"
    @current_host << ":#{new_uri.port}" if new_uri.port != new_uri.default_port
  end

  if new_uri.relative?
    if path.start_with?('?')
      path = request_path + path
    elsif not path.start_with?('/')
      path = request_path.sub(%r(/[^/]*$), '/') + path
    end
    path = current_host + path
  end

  reset_cache!
  send(method, path, attributes, env.merge(options[:headers] || {}))
end
```

Time to break out the debugger and see what `method` is here. Sticking a `binding.pry` before the final line in that method, and a `require 'pry'` in the test. It turns out `method` is `:post` and, for interest's sake, `new_uri` is a `URI` object with our remote form's URL.

Where's this `post` method coming from? `method(:post).source_location` tells me:

```
["/Users/ryan/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/1.9.1/forwardable.rb", 199]
```

That doesn't seem right... Does Capybara have a `def post` somewhere?

```
capybara (master)★ack "def post"
lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb
76:  def post(*args, &block); browser.post(*args, &block); end
```

Cool. We know that `browser is a`Capybara::RackTest::Browser` object. The class beginning gives the next hint:

```
class Capybara::RackTest::Browser
  include ::Rack::Test::Methods
```

I know that `Rack::Test::Methods` comes with a `post` method. Time to dive into that gem.

**lib/rack/test.rb**

```
def post(uri, params = {}, env = {}, &block)
  env = env_for(uri, env.merge(:method => "POST", :params => params))
  process_request(uri, env, &block)
end
```

Ignoring `env_for` for the time being, what does `process_request` do?

**lib/rack/test.rb**

```
def process_request(uri, env)
  uri = URI.parse(uri)
  uri.host ||= @default_host

  @rack_mock_session.request(uri, env)

  if retry_with_digest_auth?(env)
    auth_env = env.merge({
      "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"          => digest_auth_header,
      "rack-test.digest_auth_retry" => true
    })
    auth_env.delete('rack.request')
    process_request(uri.path, auth_env)
  else
    yield last_response if block_given?

    last_response
  end
end
```

Hey, `@rack_mock_session` looks interesting. Where's that defined?

```
rack-test (master)★ack "@rack_mock_session ="
lib/rack/test.rb
40:          @rack_mock_session = mock_session
42:          @rack_mock_session = MockSession.new(mock_session)
```

In two places, very close to each other. What's on and around these lines?

```
def initialize(mock_session)
  @headers = {}

  if mock_session.is_a?(MockSession)
    @rack_mock_session = mock_session
  else
    @rack_mock_session = MockSession.new(mock_session)
  end

  @default_host = @rack_mock_session.default_host
end
```

Ok then, so it ensures it is a `MockSession` object. What's `MockSession` and how is its `request` method defined?

```
def request(uri, env)
  env["HTTP_COOKIE"] ||= cookie_jar.for(uri)
  @last_request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  status, headers, body = @app.call(@last_request.env)
  headers["Referer"] = env["HTTP_REFERER"] || ""

  @last_response = MockResponse.new(status, headers, body, env["rack.errors"].flush)
  body.close if body.respond_to?(:close)

  cookie_jar.merge(last_response.headers["Set-Cookie"], uri)

  @after_request.each { |hook| hook.call }

  if @last_response.respond_to?(:finish)
    @last_response.finish
  else
    @last_response
  end
end
```

I'm going to go right ahead here and assume `@app` is the Rack application stack. By calling the `call` method, the request is routed directly to this stack, rather going out to the world.

I conclude that this behaviour looks like its intentional and that I can indeed rely on it being that way.